# How to I explore data by a certain column in R

Tags: r, visualization, summarization

I'm having difficulty exploring, summarising and vizualizing a data frame by a specific column. My data "services" is in the following format (I will insert only the first 5 rows, as my data is very large:

[image]

```
services = data.frame(ID = 1:5,
           Sex = c('F','F','M','M','M'),
           Internet_Service = c(rep('Fiber optic', 2), rep('DSL',3)),
           Phone_service = c('Yes', 'Yes','Yes','No', 'No'),
           Payment_method = c('transfer','transfer','bill','bill','bill'),
           Monthly_charges = c(23,45,54,65,65),
           Total_Charges = c(78,67,98,67,90),
           Churn = c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'))
```

I have explored the data by 'Churn' (please see the code below).   I would now like to explore by 'Total_Charges', but this is numeric data rather than a factor and I'm not sure how to proceed.  I would like to generate summaries and graphs.

```
services %>% 
  group_by(Churn) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n())%>% 
  mutate(percent = prop.table(Count)*100)%>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Churn, -percent), percent), fill = Churn)+
  geom_col(fill = c("#505050", "#D3D3D3"))+
  theme_bw()+  
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,100))   + 
  xlab("Churn") + 
  ylab("Percent")+
  ggtitle("Churn Percent")
```

Could you please help me to figure out?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
    services %>% 
    group_by(Sex) %>% #you can use any of the factors to group by
    summarise(mean=mean(Total_Charges))
    services %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sex,Total_Charges))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    theme_bw()
```